# Updating a data object with a new value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to update a data object with a new value. I have

```
 if($("#ArticlesHolder").data(event.data.id) != null)
    {           
        $("#ArticlesHolder").data(event.data.id, {name:event.data.name, nr:newNr, price:event.data.price, articlenr:event.data.articlenr});
    }
```

Now I want to update a existing data object on `$("#ArticlesHolder")` but I only want to update one value not all values.  How do I, for example, only update the `nr` to `nr +1`?

Comment: I believe the example in your edit will work.

Comment: Hogan: you were right. I've moved the edit out to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's possible to change a data value simply but somehting like:

```
$("#ArticlesHolder").data(event.data.id).nr = '52';
```